# ZingChart change plot CSS depending on X-Scale

Tags: angularjs, charts, zingchart

I'm using a ZingChart with AngularJS.

I have a simple chart, but I would like my plot to be red if it's in the past (if the x-scale date < current Date).

I found out that I can set some certain rules to

```
"plot":{
"rules":[
    {
        "rule":"%v  20 && %v < 30",
        "line-color":"#f93",
        "line-width":"8",
        "line-style":"dashed"
    },
]
```

Which is going change css if the plot values are between 20-30. My question is ->
How can I change plot background color DEPENDING on the X-scale value? I am not able to refernce x-scale propery on plot property..

Answer (score 7):

You would be looking for the %scale-key-text token instead of simply the %v. %scale-key-text will target the scale-x axis. 
http://www.zingchart.com/docs/basic-elements/zingchart-tokens/

```js
var myConfig = {
  "type": "line",
  "title":{
    "text":"%scale-key-value"
  },
  "subtitle":{
    "text":"the parsed value"
  },
  "crosshair-x":{
    "plot-label":{
      "text":"%scale-key-value: $%v",
      "decimals":2,
      "transform":{
        "type":"date",
        "all":"%g:%i %A"
      }
    },
    "scale-label":{
      "visible":false
    }
  },
  "plot":{
    "tooltip":{
      "visible":false
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        rule: "%scale-key-text > 1457116200000",
        lineColor: "red"
      }
      ]
  },
  "utc":true,
  "timezone":-5,
  "scale-x":{
    "min-value":"1457101800000",
    "max-value":"1457125200000",
    "step":"30minute",
    "transform":{
      "type":"date",
      "all":"%g:%i"
    },
    "label":{
      "text":"Trading Day"
    },
    "item":{
      "font-size":10
    }, 
    "max-items":14,
  },
  "scale-y":{
    "values":"30:34:1",
    "format":"$%v",
    "label":{
      "text":"Price"
    },
    "item":{
      "font-size":10
    }
  },
 "series": [
  {
    "values":[
      [1457101800000,30.34], //03/04/2016 at 9:30 a.m. EST (which is 14:30 in GMT)
      [1457103600000,31.30], //10:00 a.m.
      [1457105400000,30.95], //10:30 a.m.
      [1457107200000,30.99], //11:00 a.m.
      [1457109000000,32.33], //11:30 a.m.
      [1457110800000,33.34], //12:00 p.m.
      [1457112600000,33.01], //12:30 p.m.
      [1457114400000,34], //1:00 p.m.
      [1457116200000,33.64], //1:30 p.m.
      [1457118000000,32.59], //2:00 p.m.
      [1457119800000,32.60], //2:30 p.m.
      [1457121600000,31.99], //3:00 p.m.
      [1457123400000,31.14], //3:30 p.m.
      [1457125200000,32.34], //at 4:00 p.m. EST (which is 21:00 GMT)
    ]
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 300, 
 width: "100%"
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```